# Does OPC UA allow us to execute tasks in PLCs?

Tags: rest, opc-ua

I am quite new to OPC UA. Regarding my studies, OPC UA is an adopted standard by the industry that makes the connectivity of devices and fetches data from the shop floor (i.e server side) and delivers data to the client side for further processes such as monitoring.
For the project that I am involved, The I/Os of  Siemens PLC are directly connected to the REST interface controller. Now, I'd like to know if it is possible to employ OPC UA  to send commands to REST interface for triggering corresponding I/Os and execute workstation operations.For instance, can we trigger an actuator from client side using OPC UA?  I was wondering if OPC UA is capable of implementing such an approach?
Thanks

Comment: "If it is possible to employ OPC UA to send commands to REST interface". It is completely irrelevant -- you can also ask if OPC UA is capable of talking with SQL database, or rendering web page, or... OPC UA is guaranteed to perform OPC UA tasks, anything else is capability of your given piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Siemens 1200 and 1500 PLCs have system code that implements an OPC UA *server*.  From an application that has an OPC UA *client* library, you can connect, browse, read, write and subscribe to the nodes that represent the I/O of the PLC.

There are OPC UA client libraries from many vendors, for many languages.

I would like to learn more of the REST api that you mention. Is there a link to the product?

To answer your question.  Yes, an OPC UA Client can trigger an actuator connected to a S7-1200 or S7-1500 PLC, but, it doesn't use a REST Api to do it.

Comment: @Andrew.Cullen.Thanks for your good explanation. I should've elaborated what I mean by REST API in my question. REST API interface in my case can be any RTU(Remote Terminal Unit) that supports REST. So, basically I am dealing with S7-300 series PLC which its I/Os are connected to the RTU. S7-300 doesn't support OPC UA natively and the solution offered by Siemens is SimaticNet OPC Server software.From your answer,I understood that it is possible to write values from Client to Server in OPC UA.So in my case, I want to implement OPC UA for S7-300 PLC which is connected to the RTU.

Comment: To do this,one idea can be connecting Raspberri Pi to RTU and run the OPCUA server.So,OPCUA server is actually running on R PI.With this approach, I think it is doable to read I/Os values in OPC UA client but I am not sure if it is possible to trigger an actuator which is being controlled by PLC through RTU. I should figure it out.

Comment: The SimaticNet OPC server can only be installed for Windows PC.

Comment: If your 300 has a Ethernet port (S7-31x PN/DP), then the CPU will have an embedded web server.  You might be able to use the API in this document. https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/gb/en/view/44212999

Comment: @Andrew.Cullen.Thanks. I am afraid the communication module is not as same as the one you mentioned. The controller is composed of S7-300 CPU313C and CP 343-1 Lean which has an Ethernet port to be connected to the industrial PC(TIA V13 is installed on it).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, OPC UA is an industrial M2M communication **protocol**. It is not a tool or software application. In this regard, asking "*if it is possible to employ OPC UA to send commands to REST interface*" does not make any sense.

The capability in your question is not about the protocol. It is more about the hardware and the software you have. Does your PLC support OPCUA protocol? If so, yes you can subscribe, read and write I/O of the PLC via OPCUA.

In terms of REST interface, OPCUA "as a protocol" has nothing to do with REST interface. But, you can always write a simple application to collect data from an OPCUA Server by using one of popular OPCUA Client SDKs, and make RESTful API calls. Alternatively,  you may install a connectivity platform (e.g. KepServerEX) and use its gateway features.